# Determine transition point where the slope of data changes using VBA

Tags: vba

I am wondering if there is a method to approach this problem.

The reason I need this is because for a certain trend of data I need to use a specific formula and for the next trend of the data I need to use a different formula.

Also, the data is not simple but there are two distinct slopes. (meaning when using linear trend r^2 < 1)

Comment: A picture of your data would be helpful.

Comment: http://s32.postimg.org/bbu5ink5h/Capture.jpg

Comment: Since this question is not tagged with a specific host application (like excel or access) I presume all of this should be purely done in VBA, with all data being stored not in cells or tables but in variables. Please show us the code you have so far, especially the data structures you use for storing the data.

Comment: All data points are in excel files.I haven't started the code yet. I am thinking about using

Comment: All data points are in excel cells.I haven't started the code yet.
I am thinking about using (0,1,2,3,4) data points and finding slope and keep moving by 1 (1,2,3,4,5) then somehow calculate a difference in the 2 slopes and when they are significant. to call that the transition point

Comment: I am working with maximum of 100 rows just x and y data

Answer (score 0):

1.) Cut your data in two halfs, lets say at point number n. Lets call the first half of points S1 and the second S2.

2.) Calculate the trend lines t1 and t2 for each half

3.) Calculate the sum of squares of the deviation of S1 from t1 plus the sum of squares of the deviation of S2 from t2. Lets call this sum D(n)

4.) Now repeat this for all possible values of n, and pick the one which minimizes D(n)

I am not sure if you can use the builtin trend line functions of Excel charts for this, but the formula objects for linear regression can be programmatically reached by VBA.

Comment: This sounds like a good approach! I'll write this up real quick. Thanks